# A point-free function is shared, yet evaluated twice

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, ghci

I've been trying to understand how shared computation works in Haskell. According to my understanding, point-free shared computation should be evaluated only once (courtesy to [CSE](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC_optimisations#Common_subexpression_elimination)).

(A) For example, consider the following code and its output:

```
*Main> let foo = trace "eval foo" 5 in foo + foo
eval foo
10

*Main> let foo' = \x -> trace "eval foo'" x in (foo' 5) + (foo' 5)
eval foo'
eval foo'
10
```

As expected, `foo` is evaluated only once (CSE probably kicks in), while `foo'` is evaluated lazily twice. That is fine. I tried the above using GHCi, version 7.6.3. Next, I tried the same code in GHCi, version 8.6.5, yielding this result instead:

```
*Main> let foo = trace "eval foo" 5 in foo + foo
eval foo
eval foo
10
```

Notice that `foo` is evaluated twice now.

(B) Similarly, with GHCi, version 7.6.3:

```
*Main> let goo = const (trace "eval goo" 5) in goo () + goo ()
eval goo
10
```

but, GHCi, version 8.6.5 evaluates `goo` twice:

```
*Main> let goo = const (trace "eval goo" 5) in goo () + goo ()
eval goo
eval goo
10
```

(C) Finally, both versions yield the same result for the below:

```
*Main> let foo_wrapper x = let foo = trace "eval foo" x in foo + foo
*Main> foo_wrapper 5
eval foo
10
```

I wonder if some optimizations have been turned off by default in GHCi-8 or if the side effects of `trace` force `foo` to be evaluated somehow twice? Or was there an issue in GHCi-7? How is GHCi supposed to behave with expressions like (A) and (B)?

## (Update 1)

For scenario (C) consider the following runs in GHCi-8 (with the main difference in the second argument of `trace`):

```
*Main> let foo_wrapper x = let foo = trace "eval foo" x in foo + foo 
*Main> foo_wrapper 5
eval foo
10
*Main> :t (foo_wrapper 5)
(foo_wrapper 5) :: Num a => a

*Main> let foo_wrapper' x = let foo = trace "eval foo" 5 in foo + foo 
*Main> foo_wrapper' ()
eval foo
eval foo
10
*Main> :t (foo_wrapper' ())
(foo_wrapper' ()) :: Num a => a
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> As expected, `foo` is evaluated only once (CSE probably kicks in)

No, this has nothing to do with CSE, it's just how lazy evaluation (aka *call by need*) works: `foo` is a [constant applicative form](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form), as such it just needs to be computed (forced from a thunk to WHNF) once and can then simply be reused without any further computation. The reason that this doesn't work in GHCi-8 anymore is that 7.8 has removed the [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) in GHCi. Why is this relevant? Well, `trace "eval foo" 5` is a polymorphic expression of type `Num a => a`. And polymorphic expressions can *not* be CAFs. Thus instead of *call-by-need*, you get *call-by-name*–semantics.

The simplest way to get sharing again is to enforce CAF by making the type monomorphic, by adding an explicit signature:

```
    Prelude Debug.Trace> let foo = trace "eval foo" 5 :: Int in foo + foo
    eval foo
    10
```

Comment: I am just unsure about "instead of call-by-need, you get call-by-name–semantics": it gives the same result as if `foo` were call-by-name, but not because it actually is (AFAIU).

Comment: In Update 1 both wrappers are polymorphic though, yet one evaluates `foo` only once (the computation is worth sharing) while the other evaluates `foo` twice. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @andre_c You are incorrect: `let foo = trace "eval foo" x` is not a polymorphic binding. It is monomorphic; `foo` must have the exact type chosen by the caller for `x`. (N.B. the whole function is polymorphic, but that subterm is not!) For example, `let foo = trace "eval foo" 5; y :: Int; y = foo; z :: Double; z = foo` is fine because `foo` is a polymorphic binding in that; but `let foo = trace "eval foo" x; y :: Int; y = foo; z :: Double; z = foo` is a type error.